# Launching oVirt Template cannot find data_center

Tags: ansible, ovirt

So far I believe I am very close to getting Ansible to launch a VM template in oVirt. I'm able to authenticate without an issue, I believe specify the quota but even though it's launching a template it cannot find its data_center. No examples that I can find define data_center in the ovirt_vm module, this is what I have:

```
---
# tasks file for ovirt-template-launch
- name: Login to oVirt
  ovirt_auth:
    hostname: "{{ ovirt_hostname }}"
    url: "{{ ovirt_ind_url }}"
    username: "{{ ovirt_login_username }}"
    password: "{{ ovirt_login_password }}"
    insecure: true

- name: Create persistent SSO token
  ovirt_vm:
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
    state: absent
    name: myvm

# Gather quota/datacenter
- ovirt_quota_info:
    data_center: "{{ ovirt_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ ovirt_quota }}"
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
  register: result

- name: Run VM with cloud init
  ovirt_vm:
    name: "{{ vmname }}"
    template: centos7-template1
    cluster: Default
    memory: 2GiB
    high_availability: true
    high_availability_priority: 50
    disks:
        - size: 10GiB
          name: data
          storage_domain: mydomain
          interface: virtio
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}" 
    quota_id: "{{ ovirt_quota_id }}"
    cloud_init:
      nic_boot_protocol: static
      nic_ip_address: 10.0.1.5
      nic_netmask: 255.255.254.0
      nic_gateway: 10.0.1.1
      nic_name: eth0
      nic_on_boot: true
      host_name: testdomain.com
      custom_script: |
        write_files:
         - content: |
             Hello, world!
           path: /tmp/greeting.txt
           permissions: '0644'
```

Error is:

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data_center'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data_center'"}

Comment: Well, did you follow its directions and run with `-vvv` to get the full traceback, which would give you the exact line of python whose assumption was not validated?

Comment: Are you using the correct cluster name?